# PySide6 setStatusTip() shows QAction name

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside6

I'm learning PySide6 and I stumbled upon a weird thing.
When creating a QAction and setting the status tip, the name of the QAction is shown as a status tip instead of the actual status tip.

What am I missing here?

Here is my short example code:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Test App")
        label = QLabel("Hello!")
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setCentralWidget(label)

        toolbar = QToolBar("My main toolbar")
        self.addToolBar(toolbar)

        button_action = QAction("Test", self)
        button_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+T')
        button_action.setStatusTip('Test application')
        button_action.triggered.connect(self.onMyToolBarButtonClick)
        toolbar.addAction(button_action)

    def onMyToolBarButtonClick(self, s):
        print("click", s)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Here is the weird result:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Uhm, I don't understand, what you mean by "shown as a status tip instead of the actual status tip"? What you are showing in the image is the *tool* tip, not the *status* tip

Comment: Understood, thank for your tip :)

Comment: Write it as an answer, so we can close this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is shown in the image is a *tool tip*, and by default a tool bar shows the action's [`text()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qaction.html#text-prop) as a tooltip, unless a tool tip is explicitly set using [`setToolTip()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qaction.html#toolTip-prop).

The *status* tip, instead, is shown in the *status bar* (a [QStatusBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstatusbar.html)).

On a QMainWindow the status bar can be accessed using [`statusBar()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmainwindow.html#statusBar) (if none exists, which is the default for new empty main windows, a new one is created and returned).
Just add the following anywhere in the `__init__()` and you'll see that the `"Test application"` string is actually shown there when hovering the action:

```
        self.statusBar()
```

A status bar can also be installed on any QWidget or inherited subclass, and can be used to capture any status event received from itself or its children:

```
class MainWindow(QWidget): # note: a basic QWidget
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        button = QPushButton('Test')
        layout.addWidget(button)
        button.setStatusTip('Test application')
        self.statusBar = QStatusBar()
        layout.addWidget(self.statusBar)

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == event.Type.StatusTip:
            self.statusBar.showMessage(event.tip())
            # returning True means that the event has been 
            # successfully handled and will not be propagated to 
            # the possible parent(s)
            return True
        return super().event(event)
```

The above is what actually QMainWindow does under the hood.